# Pyspark: how to add a column with the row number?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `pyspark` dataframe. I would like to add a column with that contains the row number.

This is what I am doing

```
stop_df = stop_df.withColumn("stop_id", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

If I check the maximum value of `stop_id`, I get

```
stop_df.agg(max("stop_id")).show()
+--------------+
|  max(stop_id)|
+--------------+
|32478542692458|
+--------------+
```

while the number of rows is

```
stop_df.count()
Out[4]: 8134605
```

Comment: Recommended reading: https://towardsdatascience.com/adding-sequential-ids-to-a-spark-dataframe-fa0df5566ff6

Comment: Note that database auto-increments (or "sequences" in Oracle) do not guarantee that the increments are contiguous. IDs are allocated by blocks for performance reasons, hence IDs at the end of a block may never be used. And partial failures will result in some blocks discarded altogether. The RDBMS guarantees unicity, monotony _(although concurrent transactions may use overlapping IDs)_, but not contiguity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From spark [monotonically_increasing_id](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) docs:

A column that generates ***monotonically increasing 64-bit intege*rs**.

> The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and
>   unique, but not consecutive. The current implementation puts the
>   partition ID in the upper 31 bits, and the record number within each
>   partition in the lower 33 bits. The assumption is that the data frame
>   has less than 1 billion partitions, and each partition has less than 8
>   billion records.

Use **window** **`row_number`** function to get the row number.

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([("a",),("b",)],["id"])
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
#add partition by and order by clause if ordering required with in window.
w=Window.orderBy(lit(1))

df.withColumn("stop_id",row_number().over(w)).show()
#+---+-------+
#| id|stop_id|
#+---+-------+
#|  a|      1|
#|  b|      2|
#+---+-------+

df.withColumn("stop_id",row_number().over(w)).agg(max("stop_id")).show()
#+------------+
#|max(stop_id)|
#+------------+
#|           2|
#+------------+

df.count()
#2
```